# Como escribir en negrita texto en un archivo txt java?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

por curiosidad alguno sabra si existe alguna forma de escribir en negrita en un archivo de texto en java ?

les pondría un código de ejemplo, pero la verdad no tengo ni idea aparte de que nose si sea algo simple de hacer, entonces allí cualquier link a una página o algo así se los agradecería.

yo en mi archivo escribo asi

```
nuevoArchivo.print("     HOLA ESTE ES UN COMENTARIO PARA MI TXT" + "\n");
```

nose si sea muy fácil, allí me disculpan si es demasiado obvio

Comment: A que te refieres a escribir en negrita? Los archivos de texto plano como los `.txt` no utilizan estilos de letra ni colores. Otros archivos como Markdown o los archivos de Word pueden tener estilos, pero su estructura interna para nada es igual a la de un archivo de texto plano.

Comment: a oi encerio no se puede entonces jejeje , ok si no sabia segun yo se podia